Why does memcpy result in an unexpected value?
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double tx = 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000;
    uint64_t tx1 = 0;
    
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t));
    memcpy(&tx1, &tx, sizeof(double));
    bitset<64> b1(tx1);
    
    cout << b1 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

As I expected, the tx1 should be 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000
but b1 yields 0x43EFFFE0001FFFE0.
I'd like to know how to make b1 equal to 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000.

bitset<64> b1(0xFFFF0000FFFF0000); will do what you ask for. I am afraid it doesnt actually answer your question, but it is unclear why. Whats the purpose of the code? I am curious

Hardware binary representation of values that use different types is different. I think some software also use different binary representation to work with different numerical types; floating point types and integer types. Another type came to mind… complex numbers, however C++ doesn’t support complex numbers natively. I think you get the idea now.

I take that back. C++ supports complex numbers via the standard library. Nonetheless, it uses a different binary representation.

@ChukwujiobiCanon "however C++ doesn’t support complex numbers natively" - what do you call std::complex then, if not "native"?

0xFFFF0000FFFF0000 is some integer value, but the important thing to note is that a 64 bit wide double can only represent integers up to 53 bits.  After that you just get the closest approximation.
When that happens, you now have some double object of a value close to but not exactly 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000.
You then std::memcpy the double representation back into an integer but since the double is no longer 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000 then neither will your integer.
Another thing to note is that floating point types and integer types have different binary representations. 42 in a double does not have the same binary representation as 42 does in uint64_t. This means that; no matter what, you'll never get the same bit pattern back out of the operation.

One thing you can do is use memcpy both ways.
uint64_t start = 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000;
double tx;
uint64_t tx1;
memcpy(&tx, &start, sizeof(start));
// now `tx` is some value but it has the binary representation of 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000
memcpy(&tx1, &tx, sizeof(tx));
// now tx1 has the binary representation of 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000 since the bits never get changed


Thank you so much. May I ask one more thing?
Could you recommend a method to copy the binary representation of a double into a uint64_t variable??

@Handrix You already have that. memcpy(&tx1, &tx, sizeof(double)); stores the binary representation of what the integer 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000 was converted to when it was stored in the double.  This is why I said it will never match an integer representation.  The binary representation of 42 is different between floating point and integer types.

@Handrix you seem to confuse the value of a double with the value of the raw bytes. You can take a look eg here https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to see the difference

I greatly appreciate your help. it is very helpful.
